# WHY no Copy&Paste by keyboard in Bash/CMD

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, cmd.exe, copy-paste

I know there are a lot of threads, tutorials and questions about how to work around it, but I do not get, WHY you simply cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to insert a line for example from the browser into the bash (Linux) / cmd (Windows).

Is there a specific reason why this isn't yet implemented?

It works like this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from the source
- Right Click -> Paste in the Bash or CMD

Comment: You can... in Windows 10. Just don't use the legacy console. Simply right click on the cmd window, properties, and uncheck use legacy console.

This is because back in the days of MSDOS and Unix, they didn't have copy paste, and cmd and terminal are based on that. Also, some Linux versions let you do this, such as Mint Linux and Kali.

Comment: @grawity: You wrote a nice answer there. I wonder if maybe Canonical is gonna change that someday. They made a name for themself in making difficult decisions (often needed).

Answer (score 1):

Control key sequences like Ctrl-V have been in use in individual command line apps since the time before Mac-like windowed environments first appeared. I assume that terminal emulator developers are reluctant to break compatibility just to cater to GUI shortcut conventions, with the thinking that the majority of command line users are expecting Ctrl-V go through properly to their command line apps that use it for something and the majority of GUI users don't go anywhere near the command line.